# Keep indentation of wrapped lines in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio, indentation, word-wrap

In Visual Studio 2008, is there a way to keep the indentation of automatically wrapped long lines? (Only need it for C#.)

When word wrap is turned on, it looks like this:

```
        var a = SomeFunctionOrWhateverWithSuperLongName(parameter1,
parameter2);
```

I want it to look like this:

```
        var a = SomeFunctionOrWhateverWithSuperLongName(parameter1,
        parameter2);
```

I know some text editor can do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, code formatting settings can be changed at `Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> [Your Language] -> Formatting`.

I believe it's not supported under plain VS. However, some addins might provide this feature.